Implementing stoicism in daily life
In the Meditations of Marcus Aurelius there is a quote:
"Begin each day by telling yourself: Today I shall be meeting with interference, ingratitude, insolence, disloyalty, ill-will, and selfishness – all of them due to the offenders’ ignorance of what is good or evil... Neither can I be angry with my brother or fall foul of him..."
From a reddit post, a user sums up the idea in simpler language.
"Today I'll meet (obnoxious people). But they don't mean to be (obnoxious), they just don't know any better. But I do know better, and I won't let them make a (jerk) out of me. So dumb (nonsense) from (annoying people) can't bother me."
The problem I find is that merely telling myself this idea doesn't have much effect. I might remind myself from time to time. Nevertheless, inconsiderate people continue to bother me.
The same applies to other stoic ideas. Let's say I remind myself "life is short", and in 100 years or much sooner, no one will remember who I am. Therefore, this ought to impart courage, and the ability to do the right thing. But in fact, merely thinking about the meditation may have little effect on my mentality or actions.
The question is... how do you convert a thought ("I won't let inconsiderate people bother me") into meaningful improvements in your life, and in your mind... if simply thinking about the meditation doesn't actually accomplish much.  It seems to me similar to saying "Be happy, and do not be sad".   "But calm, and do not be angry".   And yet... how effective are such thoughts?

Nuke your bad feelings with a little deliberately verbalized charity. "Goddamn motherfcking sonofabitch! Why would you do that?! Aaaaaarrgghhh... May [God's blessing and guidance]/[peace, joy, and virtue] be upon you."

How do you get to Carnegie Hall?

That's indeed a famous quotation. It didn't work for me either, in isolation.
But there's another tool that might help: compassion. From WP:

Compassion is sensitivity to the emotional aspects of the suffering of others. When based on notions such as fairness, justice, and interdependence, it may be considered partially rational in nature.

Our anger is often considered a secondary emotion, by psychologists, that is, it usually arises as a psychological defense in response to emotional pain or hurt. We get angry because we reject others reject us, take advantage of us, misunderstand us, or otherwise treat us unfairly.
It's a common theme in philosophy of wisdom, virtue, and vice, that one simply must forgive or otherwise identify with and apply compassion to the situation. It's not good enough to recognize that your fellow human is selfish, but that you have an ethical duty to harmonize with them to prevent the escalation of negativity.
While typically a religious or philosophical theme, it is recognized by advantageous by positive psychology too. There's a saying sometimes attributed to the Dalai Lama, and sometimes to Alcoholics Anonymous, that being angry with someone is like drinking poison and expecting harm to come to them. Certainly there are times for anger, in defense of one's life, for instance, or as a natural expression of injustice, but anger, even from a psychological perspective causes stress; and stress has negative effects on the mind and body. (Google Scholar)
There are many ways to defeat anger and negativity, but one quick way is by observing the prevalence of the fundamental attribution error. Sometimes we think people are bad, when they merely do bad things because of the circumstances they are in. If we can see ourselves in their shoes, it makes it easier to be accepting. There was an anecdote by an author when a couple of young children provoked the ire of a the author, and the author made a comment to the father who seemed neglectful. The father apologized profusely and relayed that the children's mother had just been killed. The author went from anger to sorrow by reframing the situation.
While there is no magic bullet, cognitive reframing is a well known psychological technique that allows a person to do exactly that. From WP:

Cognitive reframing is a psychological technique that consists of identifying and then changing the way situations, experiences, events, ideas, and/or emotions are viewed.1 Cognitive reframing is the process by which such situations or thoughts are challenged and then changed. In the context of cognitive therapy, cognitive reframing is referred to as cognitive restructuring.

If you are having a hard time of moving to compassion, you have to come to a reframing technique that works for you. Good luck!

Never hate your enemies, it affects your judgment — The Godfather

@Rushi Well you took that to a murderous place. ; )
